# How to handle many bootstrap modals on a single html page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would have 10 bootstrap buttons on a single html page.
Each button opens a ootstrap modal filled with a html fragmen via an ajax request.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"></div>

$('#myModal').modal();
```

Should I create 10 different divs with 10 different ids? Or even 10 different instances?

```
 var dialogInstance1 = new BootstrapDialog({
            title: 'Dialog instance 1',
            message: 'Hi Apple!'
        });
```

or

should I create ONE dialog?

I would expect kind of caching problems when I open modal1, then just when I open modal2 I see still for some miliseconds modal1 html fragment from a prvious ajax request.

And how should I create those modals? The samples should this:

```
        $('#myModal').modal();
```

and the instantiation? This is very confusing.

Can someone please share his experience how to approach with many bootstrap modals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect kind of caching problems when I open modal1, then just when I open modal2 I see still for some miliseconds modal1 html fragment from a prvious ajax request.

Assuming you're referring to `data-remote`'s caching, you will probably be able to disable that in Bootstrap v3.2.0 (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13183/ ).

However, I'd still recommend against using `data-remote` since it doesn't give you much control. It:

- doesn't provide or easily let you do any error handling
- doesn't give any "loading..." indication
- forces you have to generate modal HTML on the server side (as opposed to, e.g., returning JSON from the server and using client-side templating)

IMO, you should:

- include just one instance of the blank modal markup
- setup your own click event handlers on the buttons that summon your modal
- initiate the AJAX request in your click event handler
- use client-side templating to generate a corresponding modal using the results of the request
- use `$(...).modal()` or `$(...).modal('show')` (depends on how your templating works) to show the modal after the templating completes

Comment: As the only answer you get the points. But can you still tell me when should I use this: var dialogInstance1 = new BootstrapDialog() when should I create an instance of the dialog instead of doing $('#mydialog').modal(); ?

Comment: `BootstrapDialog` is a third-party plugin and not part of Bootstrap itself.